# recovery boot hangs at "systemd[1]: Listening on Journal Socket"

Tags: debian, systemd, system-recovery

Can no longer boot into Debian testing, possibly because I accidentally uninstalled some undocumentedly critical package.

In regular boot, system hangs after confirming that the root fs is clean.

In recovery boot, it says:

```
[..] systemd[1]: systemd 235 running in system mode. (+PAM +AUDIT +SELINUX + IMA + APPARMOR + SMACK + SYSVINIT + UTMP +LIBCRYPTSETUP + GCRYPT + GNUTLS + ACL + LZ4 + SECCOMP + BLKID + ELFUTILS  +KMOD -IDN2 default-hierarchy)
[..] systemd[1]: Detected architecture x86-64.

Welcome to Debian GNU/Linux buster/sid!

[..] systemd[1]: Set hostname <..>
<..>
[ OK ] Created slice System Slice.
<..>
[ OK ] Created slice <..>
<..>
[ OK ] Listening on Journal Audit Socket.
[..] systemd[1]: Listening on Journal Socket.
```

What is the system supposed to be doing now? How to get it out of this trap?

Comment: What did you uninstall?

Comment: window and display managers forth and back, a long story ..